# How to measure power consumption in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, power-supply, power

I want to measure real time overall power consumption of my laptop and I would do it with a software.

After some searchs on the web I found out that Microsoft developed Joulemeter, a software able to track PC power consumption and to save it in CVS format. It works great on Windows 7 but not yet on Windows 8.

I use a Dell Latitude e6530 with i7-3740QM CPU @ 2.70GHz and 16GB ram memory, where Windows 8.1 is installed (work PC, not my choice).

So, which is the best way to read real-time power consumption and to track it day by day?

Comment: You cannot do this without either some external hardware (a power meter) or some incredibly specific and exhaustive profiling of your computer using a power meter and setting up some software to use those figures you got from your experiments. The only other way to get power figures from electronic devices is if they have current sensing electronics built in. Using software such as Joulemeter might get you a vague estimate but it probably won't be accurate.

Comment: As @Mokubai said, you need specialized hardware to accurately measure power usage. However, I tried running Joulemeter on my Windows 8.1 machine and had no problems. You should try installing it using the Program Compatibility Troubleshooter.

Comment: The problem is not to install it, I installed Joulmeter as well. The problem is that it cannot run the auto-evaluation procedure on Windows 8 and you must insert consumption data by your self. I know there are curren clamp or smart plug as hardware solutions, but I'm looking for a software solution and I think it is not impossible to implement since it necessary to check how much power supply is taken by the PC.